# How to find the number of rows which match a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

If I have a dataframe A like

```
A:
x.     y.     z.     a.     b.     c. 
1      0      0      3      0      0
2      0      0      5      6      5
3      0      0      6      8      2
4      0      1      8      0      6
5      0      0      20     2      0
6      0      1      3      3      7
```

How could I obtain a data frame B like: 
3 columns, each one related to a, b and c columns of data frame A.. containing the numbers of rows which match the following condition:

The number of times where a, b and c values are among 5 and 10, (5 <= i <=10) AND z value is equal to 1. For instance: in column a, the row 3 is 6 which is >5 and < 10, but z. value is not 1 then that row is not count. On the other hand in the row 4, a. is >5 and < 10, and z. value is 1, then this row is counted.

B would be like:

```
B:
a.      b.      c.
1       0       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tidyverse` tools. The approach is to reduce to only the rows that have `z == 1` using `filter`, and then use `summarise_at` to condense the other rows. We first apply the function `(. > 5 & . < 10)` which makes a logical vector for whether or not each of `a, b, c` are between 5 and 10, and then wrap it in `sum`. When applied to logical vectors, `sum` treats `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`, so this is equivalent to counting the `TRUE` values.

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl_A <- read_table2(
  "x     y     z     a     b     c 
  1      0      0      3      0      0
  2      0      0      5      6      5
  3      0      0      6      8      2
  4      0      1      8      0      6
  5      0      0      20     2      0
  6      0      1      3      3      7"
)
tbl_b <- tbl_A %>%
  filter(z == 1) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(a:c), ~ sum(. > 5 & . < 10)) %>%
  print()
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     0     2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Calum. I have a question, if I want to find the number of rows which match the same condition for two columns what could I do? the output could be just the number of rows.

In the example could be like finding for the z=1 the number of rows where columns a and b are among 5-10, that would be 0.

But if we look for the z=1, the number of rows where columns a and c are among 5-10, that would be 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809331/find-the-number-of-row-matching-conditions-on-other-rows

Answer (score 2):

Or in base R:

```
sapply(c("a.", "b.", "c."), function(x)
    nrow(df[(df[, x] >= 5 & df[, x] <= 10) & df[, "z."] == 1, ])
)
#a. b. c.
# 1  0  2
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "x.     y.     z.     a.     b.     c.
1      0      0      3      0      0
2      0      0      5      6      5
3      0      0      6      8      2
4      0      1      8      0      6
5      0      0      20     2      0
6      0      1      3      3      7", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Maurits. I have a question, if I want to find the number of rows which match the same condition for two columns what could I do? the output could be just the number of rows.

In the example could be like finding for the z=1 the number of rows where columns a and b are among 5-10, that would be 0.

But if we look for the z=1, the number of rows where columns a and c are among 5-10, that would be 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809331/find-the-number-of-row-matching-conditions-on-other-rows

Comment: @PhilippeCorner I've added a short base R solution in response to your new question. Please take a look. You can close the question by ticking the solution that best answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[z. == 1, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 5 & x < 10)) , .SDcols = a.:c.]
#   a. b. c.
#1:  1  0  2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help akrun. I have a question, if I want to find the number of rows which match the same condition for two columns what could I do? the output could be just the number of rows.

In the example could be like finding for the z=1 the number of rows where columns a and b are among 5-10, that would be 0.

But if we look for the z=1, the number of rows where columns a and c are among 5-10, that would be 1.

Comment: @PhilippeCorner I am not getting your comment.  Could you please update your question or post as a new question.